# Link in the dart theme in web appbuilder

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder

I'm using the dart theme in the web appbuilder. When I add a link in the Attribute tab, it won't show in the banner. Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot showing those items you've mentioned?